# What's the recommended method to run asp and asp.net applications from NAS?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, asp.net

This is our setup:

- Windows 2008 Hyper-V
- One Windows 2008 Enterprise VM with IIS

We have a NAS which stores all the websites.

When trying to run the applications directly from the NAS we encountered security problems because of dlls which can't run directly from the the NAS.

What setup do you recommend if we want to centralize our data on the NAS but also run the websites from that location.

txn ;-)

Comment: What sort of NAS? what protocol (CIFS/SMB?)

Comment: it really is a rather cheap conceptronic NAS which uses the SMB protocol, i think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of your problem is most likely that the default Code Access Security (CAS) settings for .NET consider your NAS to be an untrusted source and won't run code from untrusted sources.  There are ways to modify the CAS policy to fix your problem.  But honestly, the better solution is to switch to something like iSCSI or a fibre channel SAN.

[Here](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=run+.net+from+network+drive&btnG=Search&aq=f&oq=&aqi=) are plenty of links describing the problem in more detail.

Comment: that is idd the problem, i think, i've added the NAS as trusted source, but still get strange errors...

Comment: Are you sure?  The place this needs to go is not the Trusted Sites list in the Internet Options control panel.  It's specifically for the .NET runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You say there are "dlls which can't run directly from the the NAS" but this seems a little odd. What is the problem with those dlls?

By the sound of it you have a reasonably big system there. If so I would stop attempting to use a NAS and use an iSCSI box instead. iSCSI servers aren't that expensive these days. It seems to me that this is one of those "Doctor sysadmin, it hurts when I use a NAS" moments.

JR

Comment: it is a good suggestion idd, but you probably know how it goes, i have to sell it to the bosses... but if that's the only good solution, they have to take offcours, that's why i asked this question, maybe there are others ways, txn ;-)